# Diagram ( histogram and box chart interpretation)

Tags: statistics

Which diagram motivation corresponds best to variable B?

(I) A box diagram reveals a deviating observation

(II) A histogram makes the skewness in the distribution clear

(III) None of the above alternatives

Diagrams

[image]

[image]

My thinking:
Even though it is skewed to the left, it is not clear. And the box chart shows more than one deviating observation therefore (III) is the correct answer. Am I thinking right? Is the answer correct?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Box plots are nice for comparing two distributions, while histograms are nicer for visualising a single distribution. This is because horizontal box plots can be stacked vertically, but it's harder to compare vertically stacked histograms, and putting them on the same graph is a mess. I think the histogram is much more informative in this case, as you can clearly see a cliff and left skewedness. The box plot looks symmetric with 5 outliers which is not true. Compare it to the histogram which has huge gaps if you consider everything sans the leftmost 5 data points. All in all the box plot provides nice summaries of key features of a distribution but loses details in the process.